# With jquery, match single character followed by colon and wrap in span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

If I have the following html:

```
<p>e: 1-800-hello-49</p>
<p>another line</p>
<p>
    f: 1-800-hello-49
    g: 1-800-hello-49
</p>
```

I want to be able to detect a character followed by a colon at the beginning of a line so that I get the following output:

```
<p><span>e:</span> 1-800-hello-49</p>
<p>another line</p>
<p>
    <span>f:</span> 1-800-hello-49
    <span>g:</span> 1-800-hello-49
</p>
```

I have tried playing with regex but I have a hard time grasping regex for this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$('p').html(function(idx, html){
    return html.replace(/\b([a-z]:)/ig, '<span>$1</span>')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QMrjJ/)

Comment: if it is a single character after colon (as you are using in regex) then it is better to use substring..

Comment: @Mr_Green look at the third `p` element there can be multiple instances

Answer (score 2):

```
var pattern = /^\s*(.:)/gm;

$('p').html(function(i, $html) {
    return $html.replace(pattern, '<span>$1</span>');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zJtdX/2/)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
$('p').each(function() {
   var html = $(this).html();
   if(html.charAt(1) == ':')
   {
       $(this).html( '<span>' + html.charAt(0) + '</span>' + html.substr(2) );
   }
});
```

Of course this will only work with jQuery. If you use vanilla javascript, let me know so I can update the code.

Comment: This will not work when there are two lines that need to be updated inside a single p tag.